# Removing extra spaces from user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, strings

I want to take user input strings and add them together with proper spacing.

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Words Go Here"></input>
<button id="addWords">Add Words</button>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function () {

 $('#addWords').on('click', addWords);

 function addWords() {

    var value = $('#input').val();
    var firstChar = value.charAt(0);
    var lastChar = value.slice(-1);

     if ((/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(value)) && (value !== '')) {

         if (firstChar == ' ' && lastChar == ' ') {

            value = value.trimLeft().trimRight();

         } else if (firstChar == ' ') {

            value = value.trimLeft();

         } else if (lastChar == ' ') {

            value = value.trimRight();

         } else {

            value = value;
        }

        $('#output').append($('<span></span>').text(value + ' '));

     } else {

        alert('Please use characters only.');

     }
 }

})();
```

**Example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zh7vf/10/)

Is there a less-bulky (e.g. multiple `if else`s) method for stripping away additional spaces?

Comment: If my current answer doesn't suffice then could you please elaborate further on what you're after, I might've misunderstood you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding the intent of your script you don't need the if elses at all.

For starters not having a space to trim when calling trim(Right or Left) is not a problem. No errors are thrown. So you could just do this:

```
function addWords() {
    var value = $('#input').val();

    if ((/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(value)) && (value !== '')) {
        value = value.trimLeft().trimRight();
        $('#output').append($('<span></span>').text(value + ' '));
    } else {
        alert('Please use characters only.');
    }
}
```

For simplicities sake instead of `value.trimLeft().trimRight()` you can just use `value.trim()`.

**Edit:** Also as Dagg pointed out(see comments below) `String.prototype.trimLeft()` and `String.prototype.trimRight()` are non-standard but `String.prototype.trim()` is in the spec's for ES5.

Comment: Note that `String.prototype.trim` [isn't available in older browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#String.prototype.trim). However, jQuery has its own browser-independent [`$.trim()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) you can use instead

Comment: Why `value.trimLeft().trimRight()` instead of just `value.trim()`?

Comment: @Dagg Mostly to prove the point that trim functions don't have to have something to remove. But you are right. Edited to include trim() as option.

Comment: Probably also worth noting that `trimLeft` and `trimRight` are non-standard (but `trim` is in ES5).

Comment: Noted (see edit;)

Answer (score 0):

It can also be made even more compact, using the regexp to check both for letters only and for not empty word, so firing an exception when the latter happens.
It also uses jQuery `trim()`, as rightly recommended by @Flambino.

```
function addWords() {
  try {
    $('<span>' + $.trim($('#input')).match(/^\w+$/)[0] + ' </span>').appendTo($('#output'));
  }
  catch (e) {alert('Please use characters only.');}
}
```